# Why do ../ and ../../ finding the same file?

Tags: css, path, directory, subdirectory

This is an academic query as I basically have things working two ways but surely one should fail. No? (Sorry I don't know why but I always struggle with paths and this has me flummoxed.)

I have just moved the HTML of three sections out of the main file and am now using an include.

Structure now is:

```
root - vendor - datepicker - dist -etc- datepicker.css
     - beta   - main.php
              - static - date.inc
```

In the `main.php` file I  used to have a

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/
    bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

When I moved the link up to the `.inc` file in the `static` directory (one level up) I thought I should add an extra `../` but was not sure if the css would be called in the new file or in the `main.php` where the include is called. So I tested both

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/
bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../vendor/
bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

BOTH worked. I inspected in chrome and then tried `../../../` and that worked fine too.

I thought the directory form of `../` meant down one from the current level.

To quote on page I just looked at:

> Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
>
> Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)

I realize this is an idiot question and I know I have to sort out proper document paths at some stage but this has me completely confused.

Comment: Avoid the confusion - use **/vendor**, which will work relative to document root.  If you use relative URIs, moving the file around may break your site.

Comment: well, it shouldn't be. What does Network tab of Chrome's Developer Console tell (you might need to clear the results of the Network tab & reload the page for accurate results)?

Comment: What web server are you using? My thought is that your answer lies there.
Often web servers will serve from multiple directories at once, which is why all the variations you tried work.

Comment: Using Xampp. First time I have really used Network tab (thanks for sending me there). 1st time I looked both CSSs were doubled up with one in red but every time since then  (even disabling the cache) they have shown up as normal. I am pretty sure @constnt has it correct below. Thanks for the thought peoples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the page you looked at is right ./ means from current working directory, and ../ means go up one directory, ../../ up 2 dir's and so on.. but what happens if 1 directory up is your root folder and you  do a ../../? the answer is you'll still be in the root directory, you can only go so far up.  this is precisely what happened to you check out your structure, "root - vendor - datepicker" I can elaborate further if you wish. I hope this helps.

Comment: Aha - now THAT makes sense. Never thought of that. Will double check in the morning but looks about right....  But ONLY if the CSS url is served from the ORIGINAL `main.php` (I was not sure but guess I am now). So the CSS is evaluated after the `include` which I suppose is logical. 90% sure you deserve the "answer" but I am so tired I will wait until I check in the morning before giving you the Grand Prize. But thanks for that.